# File upload to an application server through a web client

Tags: java, php, sockets, web-applications, file-upload

I'm actually on a project using sockets communications in Zend Framework.

We have an application server (Java) hosted on a server, and a web client on another server, in php.

The application server is the only one having access to the database, and we'd like to be able to send a file from the web client to the server, via file upload.

While this is easy when everything happens on the same server, we don't really know how to do it this way.

We thought about uploading the file temporarily on the web server, then send it asynchronously from the web server to the application server, and delete it in the web server when it's done, via cron jobs for example.

Problem is that it will take some room, seems quite heavy and has an unnecessary step in the sending of files. It will also requires to make a database to keep track of the files, so that solution doesn't seem to be optimal.

Is there a simpler way to do it that we didn't think about ?

Comment: What's the reason you can't directly upload to the Java application?

Comment: Because we don't know how to do it directly from the POST data to the Java app, we can if it's possible.

Comment: Simply don't post to your PHP app but to your Java app.

Comment: It isn't a java web app, but a java server application, wouldn't that be an issue ?

Comment: Well... How where you planning to do the upload server side to the Java application?

Comment: I counted on reusing what I did for the download :-/